# NodeJS: Create api that will manage to generate the for loop as dynamic based on key value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a MySQL table looking something like this as below:

```
id   product_id  option_type
-------------------------------
14       6           2
15       6           1
16       6           1
17       6           2
18       6           2
```

Applying the sql query with the help of `Sequelize ORM` on above sql table render the below array of objects and on `option_type` key I need to generate a combination of collection based on the `option_type` value:

```
var records = [
{ id: 14, value: "M", product_id: 6, option_type: 2 },
{ id: 15, value: "White", product_id: 6, option_type: 1 },
{ id: 16, value: "Black", product_id: 6, option_type: 1 },
{ id: 17, value: "S", product_id: 6, option_type: 2 },
{ id: 18, value: "L", product_id: 6, option_type: 2 }]
```

And I have managed with the `Array.prototype.filter()` method to create the combinations.

```
const option_type_1 = records.filter((el) => { return el.option_type == 1 });
const option_type_2 = records.filter((el) => { return el.option_type == 2 });


for(const opt1 of option_type_1) {
  for(const opt2 of option_type_2) {
    const options = {
      "opt_one_id": opt1.id,
      "opt_two_id": opt2.id,
    };
    optionList.push(options)
  }
}
```

And getting the response as below...

```
{
  "data": [
  { "opt_one_id": 15, "opt_one_value": White, "opt_two_id": 14, "opt_two_value": M },
  { "opt_one_id": 15, "opt_one_value": White, "opt_two_id": 17,"opt_two_value": S },
  ...and so on
]}
```

Now, How can I manage it as dynamically when option_type is added more.

Eg. now we are considering option_type = 1 and option_type = 2, but in future if one more option is added then option_type = 3 will be also there in the collection.

So, in that case how to manage this collection with the key name as well so at that time it will become something like this

```
{ "opt_one_id": 15, "opt_two_id": 14, "opt_three_id": 17 },
```

So any `option_type` is added or deleted it will be managed accordingly.

Thanks in advance !!!

=== Updated ===

Consider this base table of option_type

```
id   option_type
-----------------
1     Colour
2     Size
```

So, accordingly it will generate the combinations as below

```
15 (White) * 14 (M)
15 (White) * 17 (S)
15 (White) * 18 (L)
16 (Black) * 14 (M)
16 (Black) * 17 (S)
16 (Black) * 18 (L)
```

Comment: In the response ```data``` what is the correlated values of *opt_[option_n]_id: ???*

Comment: `"opt_one_id": 15` is the value which is rendered on a query `WHERE option_type == 1` same way for `"opt_two_id": 14` `WHERE option_type == 2`

Comment: For every id_one attach all id_two? The code do that. Am i right?

Comment: For every id_one attach alla id_two? Sorry mate, can't get your question.

Comment: *optionList* result is ```[{ "opt_one_id": 15, "opt_two_id": 14 }, { "opt_one_id": 15, "opt_two_id": 17 }, { "opt_one_id": 15, "opt_two_id": 18 }, { "opt_one_id": 16, "opt_two_id": 14 }, { "opt_one_id": 16, "opt_two_id": 17 }, { "opt_one_id": 16, "opt_two_id": 18 }] ```. So for every_one id add all the two_ids. See the result

Comment: I dont' fully undestand what you are trying to archieve.

Comment: Please check my updated question... and yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the results using `option_type` using underscore as follows.

```
const options = _.groupBy(records, record => record.option_type);

console.log(options);
```

once you grouped, you will get the following structure.(consider we have 3rd option type now)

```
options = {
    
    1: [
         {id: 15, product_id: 6, option_type: 1}, 
         {id: 16, product_id: 6, option_type: 1}
       ],

    2: [
          {id: 14, product_id: 6, option_type: 2}, 
          {id: 17, product_id: 6, option_type: 2 },
          {id: 18, product_id: 6, option_type: 2 }
       ],
   3: [
          {id: 19, product_id: 6, option_type: 3}, 
      ]
    
    }
```

after that, you can use **for..in** and **for** loop in combination to get the desired results as follows

```
const keys = Object.keys(options);
const rootItem = options[keys[0]];
delete options[keys[0]];
const finalResults = [];

for(let i =0; i< rootItem.length; i++) {
    for (option in options) {
        for (let j = 0; j<options[option].length; j++) {
            let item = {};
            item[`option_type_${rootItem[i].option_type}`] = rootItem[i].id;
            item[`option_type_${options[option][j].option_type}`] = options[option][j].id;
            finalResults.push(item);
        }
    }
} 

console.log(finalResults)  

[ { option_type_1: 15, option_type_2: 14 },
  { option_type_1: 15, option_type_2: 17 },
  { option_type_1: 15, option_type_2: 18 },
  { option_type_1: 15, option_type_3: 19 },
  { option_type_1: 16, option_type_2: 14 },
  { option_type_1: 16, option_type_2: 17 },
  { option_type_1: 16, option_type_2: 18 },
  { option_type_1: 16, option_type_3: 19 } ]
```

Comment: It sounds what I am looking for... let me try and will update you.